# Compiling VLC for iOS:svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL

Tags: ios, svn, vlc

When I run compileVLCforiOS.sh :

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source': could not connect to server (http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com)
```

I looked into other FAQ,and try use https instead of http in script file,but it didn't work.And my MacBook Pro did't install Cisco AnyConnect.

What't the problem with that?:(

Comment: Are you able to open this repo in browser? (http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source)

Comment: yes ,both in http or https

Comment: @InderKumarRathore or it's about my VPN?

Comment: Seems like your system is not connecting to this url, I suggest you to change your network and then try again.

Comment: OK,I will try,thanks!